# Do I need to deal with warnings about row count and spatial index to use pgRouting?

Tags: qgis, postgresql, pgrouting

After read this nice post from underdark [A Beginner’s Guide to pgRouting](http://anitagraser.com/2011/02/07/a-beginners-guide-to-pgrouting/), although I still have some little problems, I think I can begin the "Creating a routable road network" stage right now.

I got a polyline shapefile already, but after I Add PostGIS Layers, I open PostGIS Manager and I don't know if these two red triangles would bother me later on:

- There is a significant difference between estimated and real row count. Consider running VACCUUM ANALYZE.
- No spatial index defined.

If they do, what can I do？

[image]

Comment: You should post new questions for each question. That way you will get better, focused answers.

Comment: Please post one question per thread. I'll remove the last three questions from this one.